# how many update method should we write for a 15-column-table

Tags: performance, crud, dao

I got a requirement for a DAO-class to do CRUD on a 15-colunm-table and I'm so confused on whether I should write **1 method with 15 parameter** or **15 method with 1 parameter per method** or maybe something else. I finished the first choice (of course, I'm lazy :p), but this question (on title) messed me up all day, GOOGLE doesn't help me much so I post this question to ask you pro about it. For the best performance, what is the solution do you make? And to promote it, *What is the best practice for my problem?*
-
Pangea's answer reminds me of something I missed:

I have a class (MyClass) to represent the 15-column-table, and actually, I wrote 2 methods, 1st one with 15 parameters, and 2nd one with 1 parameter: the instance of MyClass.

The 1st method definitely breaks the convention (less than 7 parameters for 1 method).
But I'm thinking about when a user changes only 1 field, if we call the 2nd method, we must init a new instance. then...

Answer (score 2):

In most situations, when talking to a database from your application, the expensive part of operation is actually connecting to the database.

Creating 15 connections - or even one connection and firing 15 different commands, is pretty much always gonna be slower than connecting once and firing one command to do everything you need.

In short - one update method will be better in 99.9% of cases for crud operations...

Answer (score 0):

How about 1 update method that takes a simple class representing the table's row. for e.g. Person class for a PERSON table.